# OData v4 Client Code Generator

Tags: c#, web-services, rest, xamarin

OData v4 Client Code Generator , How developer can generate OData Entity Classes on client side,
Please explain the steps.

Appreciate Help

Thanks

Comment: What language/IDE will the client be utilizing to generate the code?  Each one will have different answers.

Comment: Thanks for reply .....I got soluton...    C#/VS2013

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the OData v4 code generator is installed. If not installed [see here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bingl.ODatav4ClientCodeGenerator)

**If your endpoint require authentication(You must manual download the metadata)**

1. Retrieve the endpoint metadata using $metadata on your favourite browser  (EX: http://MyCompany.com/ODataV4/$metadata);
2. Save the the edmx file inside your solution folder;
3. Add the code generator item on visual studio;
4. Set the MetadataDocumentUri  to the fullpath of the edmx (EX : c:\Projects\Mysolution\Myproject\metadata.edmx)
5. Right click the .tt(T4 code generator) file -> Run Custom Tool

**If it's a public OData endpoint** **[SEE tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-v4/create-an-odata-v4-client-app)**

1. Add the code generator item on visual studio;
2. Set the MetadataDocumentUri to the URL of the endpoint (EX: http://MyCompany.com/ODataV4)
3. Right click the .tt(T4 code generator) file -> Run Custom Tool

You should have all entities and necessary methods to use the ODATA endpoint.

Answer (score 1):

All ready OData code generate is given by Microsoft only .... we need to give server URL it will generate automatically.

Answer (score 0):

**Best approach (assuming you control both ends)**

Put the dto objects form the server side in to their own assembly and share that in both the server and client code.

**If you don't have / have no control over the server side**

The data you receive from such a server often depends on the query you run as you can sub select / expand / even project in to different formats it basically comes down to defining an object yourself and then deserialising the json / xml message you get from the server in to it.

**That said**

Micorsoft do have a nuget package for this if you really want to generate classes from the data in a particular query